# why Scrollview is not working under drawerlayout

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I am making an app where I have category screen on that screen I have 8 buttons on the Main screen but the last button is hidden behind ad layout so now I want that user should be able to scroll it up or down by using Scroll View but why Scroll View is not working under drawer layout. I have no idea how to solve this issue.

**XML layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/startbg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="btn1"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="btn2"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="btn3"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn4"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="btn4"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn5"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="btn5"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn6"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="btn6"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn7"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="btn7"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn8"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="btn8"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/menu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Change height to _wrap_content_ of _RelativeLayout_

Comment: @Piyush already tried this but not working

Comment: can you put out the screenshot also which you want?

Answer (score 0):

In my case NestedScrollView worked instead of ScrollView.

Also put   `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in  your relativelayout and yet its not working then plese send me your java file also so i  can check by running it.

Following is the snippet of my working layout: Please make sure that you haven't make any childview height to match parent(0 dp) inside `constrianlayout` also for scroll view `android:fillViewport="true";`

Ask me if any doubt Occur.

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/cvLayout"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">   



<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_90sdp"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/cvLayout"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
```

Comment: I have Drawer layout as Parent view and i think it accepts only 2 child's scrolling is working but now views are overlapping toolbar